# Remote Desktop over SSH to Windows 7 box

Tags: windows-7, ssh, remote-desktop, putty, ssh-tunnel

I have been using remote desktop to access a Windows 7 PC, tunneled over an SSH connection, successfully for a while now, until it suddenly stopped working.

The client is also Windows 7, and I double checked that the tunnel (with putty) was set up properly, and that remote desktop connections were enabled on the remote PC.

On the client I have a loopback adapter with a static IP of 10.0.0.1, and in putty I have 10.0.0.1:33891 forwarded to port 3389 on the remote server.

This worked fine till about a week ago, and I'm wondering what could possibly have happened? now the remote desktop client gets stuck at "configuring remote session" and then times out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the PuTTY logs show anything? Click the PuTTY icon in the titlebar, and then choose Event Log.

Comment: Putty ssh tunnel doesn't seem to work on Windows 7, I use git for source code repository and it comes with command line SSH and tunneling works great! http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Comment: Does the Windows 7 event logs show anything?

Comment: Have you installed any windows updates on your machine? any changes to windows firewall on either device? Does the SSH tunnel still establish?

Comment: tunnel establishes.  Windows updates might be the issue?  The tunnel is fine.

Comment: sometimes everything works fine and you run a windows update and it breaks something...worth a try

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the exact same thing, WIN 7 and RDP over SSH, without problems.  I've written an article on how I do it here: http://www.ronnieroller.com/articles/rdp_over_ssh_with_a_linksys_router

I'm using a different firmware on my linksys router in order to run an SSH server on it.

Comment: Nice article, gave me just the right pointers to get my rdp connections tunnelling through my linux server to my windows desktops! tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I have the same configuration as yours, Windows 7 desktop at work, SSH Server @home and a windows 7 desktop at home.

I downloaded TheTube and it worked like a charm
http://www.blogsdna.com/4671/the-tube-ssh-tunneling-tool-for-windows-7.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I wanted to post this somewhere. I also could not get an RDP connection to work over a reverse SSH tunnel. This is gonna sound wonky, but Windows 7 apparently does not like allowing remote logins to the user that initiated the tunnel. I read that somewhere and figured what the heck I got nothing else to lose so I might as well try it, but to my surprise it worked immediately. On PC-A, the target Win7 machine, I created a dummy user, logged in with the dummy user, started a reverse tunnel (with PuTTY) to PC B, and switched back to the user I wanted. Then, on PC-B, connected to PC-A via RDP and it got past the hanging Welcome screen and subsequent timeout on the first try. I hope someone finds this helpful!

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using an SSH tunnel to secure the RDP session?  RDP sessions in Windows Vista and Windows 7 are already secured via 128 bit encryption via a certificate.

Comment: I need ssh to access other machines on the network, and I have only the one port open.

Though I'll admit part of it is old-school paranoia about leaving a windows service open to the net.